# Android image overlay

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-animation

[Android Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D49i4.jpg)
Want to develope this type of screen.
when user click on first image that image is move on to third position and
second image came into the first position.and image circulation have to 
be continuous.i'm going through the lots of searching like viewpager edge effect,hollo effect,viewpager overlay but didn't find my solution.any help would be appreciate.

Comment: How narrow you could need ,i just posted the screen that i want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this link may be it help you............

Link:-http://www.devexchanges.info/2015/11/making-carousel-layout-in-android.html

or use this xml file ........

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

  <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

          <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image3"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:src="@drawable/first"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image2"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:src="@drawable/today"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:src="@drawable/all_stories"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

and use this code......

```
 int images[] = {R.drawable.all_stories, R.drawable.today, R.drawable.first}, temp;
```

enter this in the Activity and outside the all methods.

and this code in image `onclick(View view)` method .....

```
 if (view.getId() == R.id.image2) {
            temp = images[0];
            images[0] = images[1];
            images[1] = images[2];
            images[2] = temp;
            image1.setImageResource(images[0]);
            image2.setImageResource(images[1]);
            image3.setImageResource(images[2]);
        }


        if (view.getId() == R.id.image3) {
            temp = images[0];
            images[0] = images[2];
            images[2] = temp;
            image1.setImageResource(images[0]);
            image2.setImageResource(images[1]);
            image3.setImageResource(images[2]);
        }
```

its run i checked it ......

enjoy coding.....

Comment: Look like found what i want but have to first implement.

Comment: follow the instruction in the link or have look on edit answer.

Comment: ok. i 'll get back to u in a while.

Comment: Where to apply click event?

Comment: just implements OnClickListner to the activity. and set image3.setOnClickListner(this); image2.setOnClickListner(this); and override the OnClick(View view )method and put the code in it .

Comment: @a_vasim is you problem solved ?

Comment: Yes man. library is working.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a Framelayout and place all your images inside that. Decide what to do (set visibility) in the OnClickListener.

Comment: It's should be work with 100 images?

Comment: Then do it programmatically instead of the static layout.xml. Actually you don't need a FrameLayout for that. Just update the image source when the ImageView is clicked. You can store the image resource IDs in a List or a Stack. So it should be quite easy...

Comment: Did u check my android image.

Comment: Yes but I wasn't sure if you need this overley effect...

Comment: yes man i need the overflow.

Comment: "Overflow" for 100 images?